# Using Desktop Skydrive without staying logged into Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I just recently updated to Windows 8.1. With the new update, Skydrive seems to be integrated with Windows.

For privacy and security reasons, I don't want my Windows to be constantly logged into my account. However, I do want a desktop mode where I can transfer files easily. With the original Windows 8 I can do this without logging into my MS account through windows.

So, the question is, is it possible to access the Skydrive desktop mode without logging into everything in Windows?

Comment: For better or worst Microsoft has removed the ability to use Skydrive on Windows 8.1 unless you connect your profile to your Microsoft Account.

Comment: Ugh, so no solution or hacks? This is why I have a phobia of updating things; they end up functioning worse than before.

Comment: There might exist a hack, but the official stance of Microsoft is clear "Yes, you need to sign in with a Microsoft account to browse your SkyDrive and keep your files and settings in sync. If you sign in with a local account, you can only use the SkyDrive app to browse your PC. To browse your SkyDrive files, you'll need to go to SkyDrive.com." while I disagree with the requirement personally the reasons for this requirement are actually pretty good.

Comment: After months of trying to figure this out, decided to switch to MEGA.